# Oracle g11r2 installation on rhel7 return a [INS-20802] error

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, redhat, failed-installation, database-installation

I'm trying to install Oracle 11gR2 on rhel7 but I obtain an error on the final steps running the Configuration Assistant. The problem is that the log does not give any kind of information about the error:

```
INFO: Starting 'Oracle Database Configuration Assistant'
INFO: Executing DBCA
INFO: Command /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin/dbca
-progress_only -createDatabase -templateName General_Purpose.dbc -sid
oraclespm -gdbName oraclespm.mydomain -emConfiguration LOCAL
-storageType FS -datafileDestination /opt/oracle/app/oracle/oradata
-datafileJarLocation /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/assistants/dbca/templates
-responseFile NO_VALUE -characterset AL32UTF8 -obfuscatedPasswords false
-sampleSchema true -oratabLocation /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/install/oratab
-automaticMemoryManagement true -totalMemory 794 -maskPasswords false
-oui_internal -oui_internal -oui_internal -oui_internal -oui_internal
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn.handleProcess() entered.
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: getting configAssistantParmas.
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: checking secretArguments.
INFO: ... GenericInternalPlugIn: starting read loop.
INFO: Read: SYS_PASSWORD_PROMPT
INFO: Processing: SYS_PASSWORD_PROMPT for argument tag -sysPassword
INFO: Read: SYSTEM_PASSWORD_PROMPT
INFO: Processing: SYSTEM_PASSWORD_PROMPT for argument tag -systemPassword
INFO: Read: DBSNMP_PASSWORD_PROMPT
INFO: Processing: DBSNMP_PASSWORD_PROMPT for argument tag -dbsnmpPassword
INFO: Read: SYSMAN_PASSWORD_PROMPT
INFO: Processing: SYSMAN_PASSWORD_PROMPT for argument tag -sysmanPassword
INFO: End of argument passing to stdin
INFO: Completed Plugin named: Oracle Database Configuration Assistant
```

Is there a way to improve the log or have a trace to discover the error?

Thanks,
Michele.

Comment: what is th error btw

Comment: It's an anonymous [INS-20802] Database Configuration Assistant failed

Comment: Cause: the plug-in failed in its perform method

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about why but the problem seems solved. I still follow the same steps described here (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e24326/toc.htm#BHCBCFDI). Only changes I made:
- I deselected the creation of the sample schema
- I changed the SID name from a 8 letter name to a 6 (not sure if there is any limitation)

Anyway, I'm still interested in how to increase the log level of the installation.